# Getting duplicates in MySQL JOIN query

Tags: mysql, sql

I needed to join 2 tables together in a query and have the query executing properly except it is listing duplicates of the data?  I only need one copy of each record returned.

```
SELECT DISTINCT FirstName, LastName, r.Email, ListingID 
FROM TableE e
JOIN TableR r ON e.ListingAgentID=r.AgentID 
WHERE ListingFirmID = 'JNA' 
ORDER BY ListPrice DESC
```

Returns:

```
FirstName  |  LastName  |  Email      |  ListingID
-------------------------------------------------
Buck       |  Rogers    | buck@b.com  |  563214
Buck       |  Rogers    | buck@b.com  |  563214
Samm       |  Bogers    | samm@b.com  |  999999
Samm       |  Bogers    | samm@b.com  |  999999
Alan       |  Stoger    | Alan@b.com  |  232323
Alan       |  Stoger    | Alan@b.com  |  232323
Dann       |  Dammit    | dann@b.com  |  636363
Dann       |  Dammit    | dann@b.com  |  636363
Dann       |  Dammit    | dann@b.com  |  636363
Dann       |  Dammit    | dann@b.com  |  636363
```

Comment: There is no where near enough information here to answer your query. Please provide examples of the structure of your tables and specify exactly what you mean by "I only need one copy of each record returned".

Comment: If you are getting those results with a `SELECT DISTINCT` then there is some difference in the data that you are missing as `DISTINCT` will return each combination of data for a row only once so there must be some differences in the data that is being missed.

Comment: You are right joe, there was.  I missed it Distinct totally worked.

Comment: I find that DISTINCT typically is masking some other problem (a blown join, a bad schema design, etc).  Martin's request for more information was a good one.

Comment: @AlainCollins while there's some truth in your statement I don't agree with the word 'typically' - I'd prefer 'occasionally'. `DISTINCT` should not be used lightheartedly but is oft valid. A heavy word like 'typically' would be more appropriate for `goto` or `eval`.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes, I probably *need* distinct maybe once a year, where I write broken queries that could be *fixed* with join a little more often :)   I wasn't concerned enough to downvote your answer or anything.

Comment: @AlainCollins as said I agree that `DISTINCT` isn't to be used to solve every deduplication issue, and that its use might mask bad code to begin with. I do use it more often than once a year, it's not too uncommon, and oft quite unavoidable, in analytical or statistical data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT <rest of your query goes here>
```

Comment: [Impossible](http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/mysql/w/wiki/6339.queries-select-with-distinct.aspx).

Comment: It *is* valid. If this is not working your question is not right. You're showing output with 4 entirely unique rows, `DISTINCT` deduplicates those and returns only the 4. [Doc 1](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp). Or [doc 2](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/distinct.php). Even [Microsoft confirms](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187831(v=sql.105).aspx). If this doesn't work correctly there's a bug in your question, not the answer.

Comment: Yes, the data was slightly different.  I had removed a bunch of the columns in my query to make it easier to read the question.  DISTINCT did in fact work as described and is a valid answer.